# Joomla 3.8.1 Neither Alternative Menu Item Nor Layout Reflects on Front End

Tags: menu-item, com-content, layout

Within mytemplate, I created an alternative menu and an alternative layout for the com_content articles view, and neither reflects on the front end.

For com_content, in my template, I created the following files:

```
joomla/templates/mytemplate/html/com_content/article/LandingPage.php
joomla/templates/mytemplate/html/com_content/article/LandingPage.xml
joomla/templates/mytemplate/html/com_content/article/LandingPageLayout.php
```

At the top of file LandingPage.xml, the layout section contains:

```
<layout 
        title="TPL_MYTEMPLATE_COM_CONTENT_ARTICLE_VIEW_LANDINGPAGE_TITLE" 
        option="TPL_MYTEMPLATE_COM_CONTENT_ARTICLE_VIEW_LANDINGPAGE_OPTION">
    <help
        key = "JHELP_MENUS_MENU_ITEM_ARTICLE_SINGLE_ARTICLE"
    />
    <message>
        <![CDATA[TPL_MYTEMPLATE_COM_CONTENT_ARTICLE_VIEW_LANDINGPAGE_DESC]]>
    </message>
</layout>
```

Through backend, I can select the alternative menu type, but when I load the web page corresponding to menu item, the HTML corresponds to

```
/components/com_content/article/view/default.php
```

I have re-read the documentation for alternative layouts and alternative menu items and rechecked I am following instructions correctly: https://docs.joomla.org/Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla

Also, I looked for duplicate answers, and found:

[Layout Override shows up as menu Item but not as category layout](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/9603/layout-override-shows-up-as-menu-item-but-not-as-category-layout)

[Can't see alternative layout once i add xml file](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/9562/cant-see-alternative-layout-once-i-add-xml-file)

I believe I understand the logic for the mytemplate alternative menu items and alternative layouts, but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

The URL's generated through the back end for the menu items set to this alternative menu type item have the following syntax:

```
index.php?option=com_content&view=article&layout=mytemplate:LandingPage&id=1
```

Looking for alternative solutions, I then set the LandingPageLayout.php through the article's configuration Options Layout setting. The article's Options > Layout drop-down shows the alternative layout "LandingPageLayout." However, through the front end, the menu item continues to display the code from /components/com_content/article/view/default.php

To easily differentiate which php file is loading, from among default.php, LandingPage.php, and LandingPageLayout.php, I entered an HTML tag that clearly shows me which file is loading.

What am I doing wrong?

Why is the content from mytemplate article's alternative menu item and alternative layout not loading trough the front?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a really old post, but I ran across it trying to solve the same issue in Joomla 4.

The simple solution was to change the case.  The template filename need to be in all lowercase:
joomla/templates/mytemplate/html/com_content/article/landingpage.php
joomla/templates/mytemplate/html/com_content/article/landingpage.xml
joomla/templates/mytemplate/html/com_content/article/landingpage_layout.php

Comment: Well done, Scott.  Thank you for contributing some modern advice.  This is precisely what Joomla users should be doing when they find unresolved questions on this site.  Please take our [tour] and consider telling us a bit about your Joomla experience by editing your profile